# Find $\oint_{|z|=1}\log\left|\frac{1}{1+z^p}\right|\frac{dz}{z} $ where $0<p<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

Find $$\oint_{|z|=1}\log\left|\frac{1}{1+z^p}\right|\frac{dz}{z} $$ where $0<p<\frac{1}{2}$

**Attempt**
$$I=\oint_{|z|=1}\log\left|\frac{1}{1+z^p}\right|\frac{dz}{z} $$
Define, $$f(z)=  \frac{1}{1+z^p} $$
Then since $0<p<\frac{1}{2}$, so $f(z)$ has a branch point at $z=0.$ so $f(z)$ is not analytic at $z=0$.
How to solve this integral using branch cuts or otherwise?.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Please answer

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. $|z^p|$ is constant on your path of integration, hence $\log\left|\frac{1}{1+z^p}\right|$ is constant on the path of integration.

Comment: @K.defaoiteThanks. How is  $\log\left| \frac{1}{1+z^p}\right|$ constant on the path of integration? So it is analytic?

Comment: @K.defaoite $\frac1{1+z^p}$ is by no way a constant.

Comment: @user Yes I agree. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: A tip: $z=e^{i\phi}$, and $\phi$ changes from $0$ to $2\pi$ on the integration path. As $p\in(0,1/2)$, $z^p$ changes from $1$ to $e^{2\pi i p}$, hence $z^p\neq-1$ on the integration path. Inside the contour $|z|<1$. Thus, $|1+z^p|>0$ inside the contour, and there are no branch points of logarithm. Squeeze the contour close to zero, and you just have to evaluate the residual of $f(z)\frac{1}{z}$ in $z=0$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thanks a lot. But things are not clear. Please write it as an answer. I would be obliged to give your answer a check mark.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Are you saying that f(z) has no branch points?

Comment: @Svyatoslav Please reply. I cannot get you

Comment: $f(z)$ has no branch points and poles inside the contour. But $f(z)\frac{1}{z}$ - the integrand - has a single pole inside the contour (at $z=0$). Thus, the integral is equal to $2\pi i$ Res ($f(z)\frac{1}{z}$) in $z=0$. Can you evaluate it?

Comment: @Svyatoslav How does f(z) has no branch points? $z^p$ has branch point at 0. So f(z) has branch point at 0. Is this correct?

Comment: @Svyatoslav The Branch Point 0 lies inside $|z|=1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed this point...

Comment: @Svyatoslav Then how to tackle the branch point at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was correctly noted in the comment the integral is not unambiguously defined without specifying the branch cut. For an arbitrary cut intersecting the circle at the argument $\phi-\pi$ one obtains using substitution $z=e^{it}$:
$$\begin{align}
-i\int\limits_{\phi-\pi}^{\phi+\pi}\log|1+e^{ipt}|dt
&=-i\int\limits_{\phi-\pi}^{\phi+\pi}\log\sqrt{(1+e^{ipt})(1+e^{-ipt})}dt\\
&=-\frac i2\int\limits_{\phi-\pi}^{\phi+\pi}\left[\log\left(1+e^{ipt}\right)+\log\left(1+e^{-ipt}\right)\right]dt\\
&=\frac i2\int\limits_{\phi-\pi}^{\phi+\pi}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{e^{iptk}+e^{-iptk}}k\right]dt\\
&=\frac i2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k
\int\limits_{\phi-\pi}^{\phi+\pi}\left[{e^{iptk}+e^{-iptk}}\right]dt\\
&=\frac i2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k\left[\frac{e^{iptk}-e^{-iptk}}{ipk}\right]_{\phi-\pi}^{\phi+\pi}\\
&=\frac i{p}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\Im\left[e^{iptk}\right]_{\phi-\pi}^{\phi+\pi}\\
&=\frac ip\Im\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\left[e^{ip(\phi+\pi)k}-e^{ip(\phi-\pi)k}\right]\\
&=\frac ip{\Im\left[
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^{ip(\phi+\pi)}\right)-
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^{ip(\phi-\pi)}\right)\right]}.\tag1
\end{align}$$

Particularlry for the principal branch of the logarithm with the cut along the negative real semi-axis $\phi=0$ and one obtains from $(1)$:
$$
\frac{2i}p{\Im\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^{ip\pi }\right)}.\tag2
$$

Comment: This is one possible answer of course  but one can parametrize from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ for example which corresponds with the principal logarithm and get another answer as the original  integral is not properly defined without specifying which branch of $z^p$ we take

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have edited my answer to address this issue.

Comment: @Conrad What will be the solution according to you?

Comment: the solution above is just fine - there is no "the solution" as the answer depends on parametrization/choice of branch cut, so for each cut along some particular half-line you get a different answer; the usual two cuts give the answers above

Comment: @Conrad Can you please give me a reference or link on how to solve a closed countour integral round the unit circle having branch point?

Comment: not sure such exists in general as this type of integrals depend on choices of branch so are not uniquely defined